# Finding equation of a plane given 3 points

Tags: vector-spaces

Find the vector equation of the plane which contains points $A(0,1,1)$, $B(-1,2,1)$ and $C(2,0,2)$.

I did this by first finding $AB$ and $AC$ where I got $AB=(-1,1,0)$ and $AC=(2,-1,1)$. Then I did cross product with this and I got $i+j-k$. When I then used this to find equation I got $x+y-z=0$ but I am unsure why this is wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: I did this a(x-x1)+b(y-y1)+c(z-z1)=0  formula where abc is the normal and x1, y1 and z1 is one of the points given

Comment: Why do you this that this is the wrong answer? Each of the given points satisfies the equation.

Comment: So in my case, abc was (1,1,-1) so the equation became 1(x-0)+1(y-2)-1(z-1)=0

Comment: It is the wrong answer as I checked the answer In the textbook and my answer was wrong

Comment: The actual answer is x-y-3z=-4

Comment: The point $B(-1,2,1)$ is not satisfying the plane $x-y-3z=-4$. What you did was absolutely correct and the approach is also very good. When you calculate the vectors $AB$ and $AC$, you can have the cross product to get the normal vector which will give you the plane's equation.

Comment: Textbooks have been known to have errors from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your answer of `x+y-z=0` is correct. Are you sure you're looking at the correct answer in the book?

Given

```
A(0,1,1), B(-1,2,1), C(2,0,2)
```

We are able to find two vectors that lie in the plane AB and AC where

```
AB=<-1-0, 2-1, 1-1>=<-1,1,0>
AC=<2-0, 0-1, 2-1>=<2,-1,1>
```

Taking the cross products of these two vectors will give you a vector perpendicular to the plane that they lie in (our normal vector). The cross product does indeed work out to give x+y-z=0. So, using the formula for a plane, we have:

```
a(x-x0)+b(y-y0)+c(z-z0)=0
```

Where `<a,b,c>=The Normal Vector=<1,1,-1>`
and  can be any of the three given points, but in my example I'll use point A, so `<x0,y0,z0>=<0,1,1>`.

Plugging in our values, we get

```
x+y-z=0
```

Which is indeed the equation of the plane that contains the points A,B,C

To check your answer, see if each given point satisfies the equation (and thus lies on the plane).

```
Point A: x+y-z=0 => 0+1-1=0    So point A is on this plane.
Point B: x+y-z=0 => -1+2-1=0   So point B is on this plane.
Point C: x+y-z=0 => 2+0-2=0    So point C is on this plane.
```

$\therefore$ Your answer **is** correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes I am checking the right answer unless there is a mistake in the textbook. I will email my teacher and ask her.

Comment: Hello, This is the method that I understand however if you check the other answer that was given, they did a different method and got the same answer as the textbook so do you know why that method was used instead of our one

Comment: I'm not sure why the other answer used two parameters. If this were to be done using parameters, I would use one, say t, and it yields the same answer. `<x(t),y(t),z(t)>=<$$x_0,y_0,z_0$$>+<a,b,c>*t` Which, once you plug in $x_0,y_0,z_0$ and a,b,c (which you still get from the cross product), ends up giving you x=t, y=1+t, z=1-t. Or, if you solve for t, you end up with x=y-1=-z+1, which agrees with our answer.

Comment: Okay, I believe it is a mistake in the textbook then as there is no other explanation. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is by the formula $$\vec{x}=[x_a,y_a,z_a]+s[x_b-x_a,y_b-y_a,z_b-z_a]+t[x_c-x_a,y_c-x_a,y_c-y_a,z_c-z_a]$$=$$\vec{x}=[0,1,1]+s[-1,1,0]+t[2,-1,1]$$ where $$s,t$$ are real numbers
Eliminate the parameters from the system
$$x=-s+2t$$
$$y=1+s-t$$
$$z=1+t$$
It is $$x+y-z=0$$
Adding the first and the second equation:
$$x+y=1+t$$ and now plug in $$t=z-1$$

Comment: but the answer says r.(I-j-3k)=-4 so how do we get from that equation to this answer?

Comment: You must eliminate the parameters $s,t$

Comment: Oh right, also is this the only method you can use because before for questions like this, if use the cross product method and it would be right hence why I was so confused

Comment: i will send you the result

Comment: sorry, I am just struggling to understand how you eliminated the parameters

Comment: Oh right, but the textbook says that it is x-y-3z=-4 and also the coordinates next to t, isn't it (2,-1,1) as that is what I got

Comment: Ok, i hope i didn't make a mistake

Comment: Could it be that you have made a typo?

Comment: No I checked multiple times and the question u typed is the same as the one in the textbook